I want to send email to case teammember once they are getting created. Can anyone help me in this?
I want to send email to case teammember once they are getting created. But I am getting this error

SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses, null]

Can anyone help me in this?
global class CaseTeamMemberNotificationScheduler implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.queryLocator Start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Query for newly created CaseTeamMember records
        Datetime endTime = Datetime.now();
        Datetime startTime = endTime.addHours(-8);
        system.debug('==endTime=='+endTime);
        system.debug('==startTime=='+startTime);
        String query='SELECT Id, ParentId, MemberId, Member.Email FROM CaseTeamMember WHERE CreatedDate != null';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<CaseTeamMember> cmmList){
        system.debug('==cmmList=='+!cmmList.isEmpty());
        EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'My_First_Templete'];
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList= new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (CaseTeamMember teamMember : cmmList) {
            system.debug('==teamMember.Member.Email=='+teamMember.Member.Email);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            mail.ToAddresses = new String[]{teamMember.member.Email};// user.email>>> user.id==teammember.memberId
            mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            mail.setTargetObjectId(teamMember.MemberId);
           // mail.setWhatId(teamMember.ParentId);
           emailList.add(mail);
           Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
       }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
    }
}


what does this line show? system.debug('==teamMember.Member.Email=='+teamMember.Member.Email);

You might be trying to send an email with a recipient's email set as null (probably because the MemberId related to CaseTeamMember does not have an associated User record with a valid email).
